# next is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting the error while running the following code in Node.js :
TypeError: next is not a function

```
   function lastmessage(collection, path, conf, conf2, next) {
    let tmp = conf === 0 ? hotelcode : parseInt(hotelcode);
    db.collection(collection).find({
        [path]: tmp
    }).sort({
        'created_at': -1
    }).toArray(function(error, docs) {
        if (error) return next(error);
        if (docs.length > 0) {
            if (conf2 === 0) {
                console.log(docs[0].updatedAt);
                return next(null, docs[0].updatedAt);
            }
            console.log(docs[0].created_at);
            return next(null, docs[0].created_at);
        }
        console.log('empty');
        return next(null, 'empty');
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is next? how are you calling `lastmessage`, sounds like your not providing a callback for `next`

Comment: I think it seems pretty obvious: the fifth parameter that you are passing to this function is not a function

Comment: So, I assume `next` is your callback function, so, at the site of call for `lastmessage`, you need to provide a callback function with it.

Comment: @Rowland Can you explain me ? I start in nodejs I have difficulties to understand.

Comment: @AntoninHattabe [this](https://repl.it/KDQI/1) is what I mean

Comment: @Rowland Thanks mate, i resolve my pb and i understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// callback function
function someFunc(holder, document) {
 // do stuff
}

// when calling lastMessage, of course there won't be null values.
lastMessage(null, null, null, null, someFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, if the fifth param you set in this function is a function,you should define the function named next first.